# Conditional SUM and COUNT DISTINCT in the same query

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple table filled with about 500k records

```
| ID_1  | ID_2  | Date        | Fields... |
+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| 1     | 1     | 1/1/2016    | abc       |
| 2     | 1     | 2/1/2016    | abc       |
| 3     | 2     | 1/2/2016    | abc       |
| 4     | 3     | 1/2/2016    | abc       |
| 5     | 4     | 1/2/2016    | abc       |
```

I have to extract from that 36 values based on common parameters and differentiated by the date.
To reduce accesses to the database and increase performance I do a subquery, and then sum the results differentiating them with an if.
The not distinct sums work perfectly fine, but I need to count some distinct value and this returns me the correct value + 1.

```
SELECT
  SUM( IF(MONTH(Date) = 1, 1, 0) ) AS A1,
  SUM( IF(MONTH(Date) = 2, 1, 0) ) AS A2,
  SUM( IF(MONTH(Date) = 3, 1, 0) ) AS A3,
  ...
  COUNT(DISTINCT( IF(MONTH(Date) = '1', COALESCE(ID_cliente), 0) )) AS C1
FROM (
  SELECT ID_1, ID_2, Date FROM table WHERE Fields = conditions
) AS Sub
```

The C1 returns 1 if the real value is 0, 2 if the real value is 1 etc

There's a solution or I must split it into two queries?

Comment: what is `that 36 values` ? where is `ID_cliente` ? Why is month(date) being compared to a character and not a number? Sqlfiddle time. With that sqlfiddle, what is the table of Expected Results. This question is unclear.

Comment: I need to extract values for very month, but based on different parameters. So sum all by month, sum all that have a particular value in a field by month, and sum only the distinct id's by month.
It's a big but repetitive query.

Comment: Show the Expected Results in a table *after* you supply the sqlfiddle having loaded up your schema with data

Comment: What is your expected result.